# Sorting a list of lists in by the numbers' absolute values

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting, absolute

In Python, if I have an input in this format:

ex.)

```
[[1, 2, -3], [2, -64, 41], [-32, 5, 4]]
```

how would I go about sorting each list by the numbers' absolute value?
the number of lists within the brackets will depend on the user's input.

in this case I'd want the output

```
[[1,2,-3],[2,41,-64], [4,5,-32]]
```

Comment: What have you tried? or did you get a question and just sent it to SO without trying?

Comment: You have a list of lists. Which sub list's absolute value? All of them? The sum?

Comment: Looks like OP wants each list element sorted by absolute values ascending.

Answer (score 1):

`sorted` takes an option `key` argument, which is a function that tells Python which values to use to sort the items. In your case you'd want to use the `abs` function.

```
 [sorted(item, key=abs) for item in foo]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `abs` as a key function for each sub list.

```
>>> li=[[1, 2, -3], [2, -64, 41], [-32, 5, 4]]
>>> [sorted(sl, key=abs) for sl in li]
[[1, 2, -3], [2, 41, -64], [4, 5, -32]]
```